# If surface tension was reversed, what shape would a drop have?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, liquid-state

Let's say surface tension was repulsive instead of attractive. In such a case, a drop (would it be called a *drop*?) would try to expose as much surface as possible. What shape would it take? **What geometrical shape has the maximum surface area for a given volume?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fine mist would suffice.  A force like that would tear a drop into tiny pieces rather rapidly.

Alternatively, if your fictional physics which is pretty much unrelated to surface tension also required that the drop also stay together, there are many fractaline structures which have remarkably surface area to volumes.  For example, consider the [Menger Sponge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge):

[image: Menger Sponge]

The Menger Sponge is a fascinating fractal with a peculiar property.  If the process used to generate it is continued to infinity, the resulting shape has infinite surface area and zero volume!  If that's not a limit to your fictional physics problem, I don't know what is!

Comment: Don't you think the drop would simply disintegrate into its constituent molecules, rather than do anything else?

Comment: @Deep Yes.  That's what I put as the first line.  The rest is more having fun with the insanity that comes whenever you start mucking with the laws of physics.

Comment: @CortAmmon Sorry for the late reply, I just got a little doubt. Would a drop actually form this Menger sponge or any other shape as well? I've checked the Wikipedia article about Menger Sponge, and it says that this isn't the only solid with such a property. I heard the Sierpinski sponge also satisfies this. In such case, the drop can prefer both shapes right? I know that hypothetical questions can't be answered, so it's ok if I don't get a satisfactory answer. :)

Comment: @PrittBalagopal There is some difference between the Menger Sponge and the Sierpinski sponge, so there may actually be a preference.  One could look at the fractaline dimensions of them.  Menger sponges have a dimensionality of 2.72 while a Sierpinski sponge has 2.96.  I think it's highly likely that that dimensionality difference would cause one of them to be preferable, though I'm not entirely sure how to go about figuring out which way it would go.